# NextJS how to use dynamic routes with output: export in next.config.js

Tags: reactjs, next.js, tailwind-css, next.js13, nextjs-dynamic-routing

I'm making a website with NextJs 13. I have a page.tsx inside of route `watch/[type]/[id]`. The page.tsx is a server component and uses a export getMetadata function since the metadata is sent according to the parameters.

I keep getting the error:
`Error: Page "/watch/[type]/[id]/page" is missing exported function "generateStaticParams()", which is required with "output: export" config.`

Now, I don't know what the possible values are for the id since they come from an API. Using output: export is important since I need to host this site on Github Pages.

Here are the contents of `page.tsx`:

```
import options from '@/lib/options';
import { Metadata, ResolvingMetadata } from 'next';
import Main from './Main';

type Props = {
    params: { type: string; id: number };
};

export async function generateMetadata({ params }: Props, parent: ResolvingMetadata): Promise<Metadata> {
    // read route params
    const id = params.id;
    const type = params.type;

    // fetch data
    const content = await fetch(`https://api.themoviedb.org/3/${type}/${id}?language=en-US`, options).then((res) => res.json());

    // fetch keywords
    const keywords = await fetch(`https://api.themoviedb.org/3/${type}/${id}/keywords?language=en-US`, options).then((res) => res.json());
    let keywordsArray = [];
    if (keywords.results) {
        for (let i = 0; i < keywords.results.length; i++) {
            keywordsArray.push(keywords.results[i].name);
        }
    } else {
        for (let i = 0; i < keywords.keywords.length; i++) {
            keywordsArray.push(keywords.keywords[i].name);
        }
    }

    // get image url from
    const image = content.backdrop_path || content.poster_path;

    return {
        title: `WatchWave`,
        keywords:
            'watch movies, movies online, watch TV, TV online, TV shows online, watch TV shows, stream movies, stream tv, instant streaming, watch online, movies, watch movies United States, watch TV online, no download, full length movies watch online, movies online, movies, watch movies online, watch movies, watch movies online free, watch movies for free, watch streaming media, watch tv online, watch movies online, watch movies online free, watch movies for free, watch streaming media, watch tv online, ' +
            keywordsArray.join(', '),
        description: `${content.overview}`,
        openGraph: {
            type: 'website',
            url: `https://watchwave.github.io/watch/${type}/${id}`,
            title: `Watch ${content.title || content.name} for free on WatchWave`,
            images: [image && { url: `https://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w1280${image}` }],
        },
    };
}

export default function Page() {
    return <Main />;
}
```

Any help is appreciated.

I tried to look at the documentation but couldn't figure out how to solve this.

Comment: Copied your code and tested in my own project, it works perfectly fine, may be the layout or the parent layouts of that page has something to do with generateStaticParams()

Answer (score 0):

The only way I have found so far is using Next version 13.4.19.  They seem to have made a breaking change after this.

Comment: lol im using next 14.0.4

Answer (score 0):

for static export you have to tell nextjs which paths or more exactly for which slugs to generate.
Roughly it should look like this:

```
//page.tsx
export const generateStaticParams = async () => {
  const keywords = await fetchKeywords()
  const myTypes = await fetchTypes()
  // do whatever you have to do depending on data structure
  return ([
    { type: 'drama', keyword: 'crime', id: 'm123' }, // => watch/drama/crime/m123
    { type: 'science_fiction', keyword: 'space', id: 'm345' } // => watch/sience_fiction/space/m345
    // ...
  ])};

const Page = ({params}: TParams ) => {
   const myPageType = params.type;
   // ...
   return ...
}
```

Important is to return an array of objects containing your path params